# What am I doing wrong while replacing my for loop with a while loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

Here is the code using for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
        cout << "HI" << endl;
    } 
}
```

Here is my attempt to replace it with whiles:

```
int i=0,j=0;
while(i < 3) {
    while(j < 3) {
        cout << "HI" << endl;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The for loops print out "HI" 9 times, just like I want them to. I don't understand why the while loops evaluate the inner expression only once, printing "HI" out 3 times.

Comment: OMG I think I see it. I need to reset the j in every outer while loop.

Comment: YES that was it. I need a rubber duck to debug out loud to :P

Comment: This question will likely be closed as a minor typographical error. But you should add your answer to it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"OMG I think I see it. I need to reset the j in every outer while loop. "

Yes you are right. The inner loop:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
        cout << "HI" << endl;
    }
```

Resets j to zero in every iteration of the outer loop.

```
int i=0;
while(i < 3) {
    int j= 0;
    while(j < 3) {
        cout << "HI" << endl;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This answer would be better if it declared `j` within the `i` loop.

Comment: seems legit, edited it